# Variable inside if block is assigned to zero even if the if expression evaluates to false in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int a = 123,b,c;
    if(a>300) {
        b=200;
    }
    c=4556;
    printf("b = %d\n",b);
    return 0;
}
```

Now as if block evaluates to false so if block should not get executed, but the code is printing value of b as 0.
Moreover if the value of c isn't assigned after the if block is over then the code shows some garbage value for b.
Can anyone tell me why is this happening like this, as far as I know b must show some garbage value for the first case also.

Comment: *"b must show some garbage value"* - 0 is a valid garbage value.

Comment: I am getting b = -1215655948 and different value on running each time. so b holds garbage value in my SUSE12.1 system :(

Comment: @Dcoder but why is b always showing 0 only when there is some variable defined after the if block, but when there is not any definition after the if block then b shows some random value?

Comment: @Jay - No reason. `b` has a garbage value that happens to be `0` when you are testing. Formally, the result of reading or printing an uninitialized value is undefined, so you can get *any* result at all.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you initialise your variables, you will not know for sure what their values are so this is not remotely surprising. If you want your `b` variable to contain a meaningful value, then initialise it with that value.

Comment: Well as you can see I've initialized b inside if block, so that shouldn't be a problem, although if expression is evaluated to false, but why zero it should show any other random garbage value.

Comment: @JayPrakashSarma Why not zero? It is just as valid as any other integer chosen to initialise an uninitialised value. If you compiled this code on a different machine it might give another number. Don't assume anything with uninitialised data.

Comment: @JayPrakashSarma: Your statement that you have “initialized b inside if block” is false. The then-clause of the `if` statement is not executed, so the assignment to b is not executed, and b remains uninitialized. When printing b, you get zero because that is what happens to be in whatever register or memory location the compiler used in place of where the value of b would be if you had initialized it. No software, in the compiler or operating system or elsewhere, is responsible for ensuring whether you get zero or any other value there. You cannot expect any particular result.